# Track purchase without item details

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations

Is there a simplified version of the 'Track Conversion' collect tracking code that we could use that doesn't require line item details for the purchase? Our data layer is not configured to consider line item details and we only want to track if a customer made a purchase or not - don't want to track what they purchased.

Or could we we just cut out the details from the correct collect tracking like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would reserve the use of Collect Tracking Code for when you want to use Einstein Email or Web Recommendations, or Einstein Engagement Scoring.

If you just want to track whether the customer made a purchase from clicking on an email link, then add the [Conversion Tracking](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_conversion_tracking.htm&type=5) pixel code to your confirmation page and include the `conversion="true"` attribute in your `href` tag for the links that you want to track.

Comment: The reason we want to use the collect tracking is to be able to the Browse Abandon behavioral trigger which will only work with the purchase collect tracking set up

Comment: Hmm, in that case you could just add a single 'dummy' item to your Product Catalog (when setting up Einstein Recommendations) and use that SKU in your catalog for all `unique_id` values.